# Shortcut key to hide all windows on Samsung DeX

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, samsung-dex

Is there a shortcut in Samsung DeX to minimize all windows and display the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Hit Meta+Enter.

To view more shortcuts, hit Meta+!.

Pro-tip : do it from Chrome and you'll see Chrome's shortcuts as well !

Answer (score 1):

"**Meta+Enter**" will minimize all the current open windows on the desktop and pressing "**Meta+Enter**" again will reopen the windows.

You can also press "**Meta+/**" to view all the default shortcuts on Samsung DeX.

If you want more than the default shortcuts then you can install an app called "[Desktop Hub](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtechnologies.dexprofile)". This app will give you lots of extra cool shortcut keys for different stuff on Samsung DeX.

Answer (score 1):

```
win (meta) + up = maximize
wim + down = minimize
wim + m = maps
win + s = SMS
win + d = desktop/minimize all
win + f = finder/search device
win + k = calendar (kalendar??)
win + L = lock
win + enter = seems to also be show desktop
win + q = quick settings panel (wifi/bt etc on/off controls)
win + e = email
win + I = bixby, unavailable in DeX mode
win + P = music default app
win + left/win + right = pin app to 1/2 of screen side by side
```